# Trouble refreshing UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to develop a basic GPA Calculator. I have an AllCourses class that holds Course objects.

I have an AllCourses object in my CalcAppDelegate.

In my ThirdViewController I can successfully update the number of Courses in my AllCourses object. However, the problem I'm having is that when I switch to the RootViewController the UITable isn't being repopulated with the updated Courses that were added.

I tried [self reloadData] in the viewWillAppear in my RootViewController but it caused my app to close. I didn't use IB to create the views so I think it could be the case that I don't have things hooked up correctly. I did it programatically. Does anyone see anything I'm missing in my code?

Here is the link to my project http://files.me.com/aahrens/q0odzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[[self tableView] reloadData]
```

The method is implemented in `UITableView` rather than in `UITableViewController`, which is why your app crashed.

Comment: I get an uncaught exception when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: I get an uncaught exception when I do that.